# How to set a keyboard shortcut for Compiz negative screen function?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, shortcut-keys

I just updated from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. However, now the Super + m function does not change my desktop and open windows to a negative view as it previously did.

I changed the keyboard shortcut for the Compiz neg to Ctrl + Alt + m, but it still doesn't do anything. Does anyone have any idea how to make this function work again with 11.04?

Comment: Can you make sure it does not conflict with others shortcuts?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to any other keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you enabled extra [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)
2. Install [CCSM](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
3. Open **System > Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager**
4. Uncheck **Accessibility > Negative**
5. Now open **System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** and you should be able to create any binding that involves `<Mod4>` (*Windows key*) and `m`